# Vb.net and serialization

Tags: vb.net, serialization

Suppose I have the following xml content:

`<Array n="3" type="int">1 22 3</Array>`

I have created the following vb.net class:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<Serializable()> _  
<XmlRoot("Array")> _
Public Class PmmlArray
    <XmlAttribute("n")> _
        Public n As Integer
    <XmlAttribute("type")> _
        Public type As ArrayType
End Class
```

So I'm able to get the "n" value and the "type". My question is: how can I get the array content, I mean, the value "1 22 3"?
In Java I would use "@xmlvalue" but there is nothing similar in vb.net.
Can anybody help me please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<XmlText()>
Public arrayContent As String
```

- `String.Split` will help you transfer `1 22 3` to a string array, and
- `Enumerable.Select` will help you create an integer array out of a string array.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Heinzi